# How to read text file with multiple delimiter?

Tags: c++

I have a source code which reads the text file and stores into the vector which is a tuple type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, double>> VectorTuple;

VectorTuple Readfile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream File(filename);
    if (!File.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File '" << filename << "' does not exist.";
        exit(1);
    }
        
    VectorTuple data;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(File, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        int a, b; double c;
        if (ss >> a >> b >> c)
        {
            data.push_back(std::tuple<int, int, double>(a, b, c));
        }
    }

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    std::string file = "data.txt";
    auto vt = Readfile(file);
    
    for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), [](std::tuple<int, int, double> i){
        std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", " << std::get<2>(i) << std::endl;
    });
    
    return 0;
}
```

The `data.txt` contains the following data:

```
30000 | 49999 | 4
50000 | 119999 | 6.5
120000 | 279999 | 8
280000 | 499999 | 9
500000 | 999999 | 10
1000000 | 1999999 | 13
2000000 | 2499999 | 15
2500000 | 2999999 | 17.5
3000000 | 3499999 | 20
3500000 | 3999999 | 22.5
4000000 | 4499999 | 25
4500000 | 4999999 | 27.5
```

So the data are separated by space + vertical line + space (multiple delimiter).

How do I change the source code to handle multiple delimiters?

Note: the program works if the data is only separated by a space.

Comment: find and use some library which is able to read CSV files.

Comment: Also, spaces are ignored in formatted extraction, you only need to take care of `|`. And there is no need to read each line into `std::string` first and then use a stringstream. You can directly read it into int, char, int, char, double to parse the shown file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read and discard the `|` with:

```
std::stringstream ss(line);
int a, b; double c;
char s;
if (ss >> a >> s >> b >> s >> c)
{
    data.push_back(std::tuple<int, int, double>(a, b, c));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to store anything in the vector because when you try to stream `|` into an `int` the stream fails and `failbit` is set. `if (ss >> a >> b >> c)` will return `false` and the cycle ends.

To avoid this you can store `|` in a `char`, and then simply ignore it, you don't need to worry about whitespace characters, they are discarded.

You can also use the `File` stream to read directly to `a`, `b` and `c`, there is no need to use a `stringstream` in this case, it's unnecessary overhead.

```
//...
int a, b;
double c;
char discard;
while (File >> a >> discard >> b >> discard >> c)
{ 
    data.push_back(std::tuple<int, int, double>(a, b, c));          
}
//...
```

Aside from that I would prefer a range based `for` to output the results:

```
//...
for (const auto &t : vt)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", " << std::get<2>(t) << "\n";
}
//...
```

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zpKVB4HZZHnj2dto)